# Two submit event handlers on a form. One must stop the other

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have to event handlers attached to a form. The first one that fires should stop the other event if a condition is not met.

The code below does not work, as both events will be triggered. Can you help me?

Thanks!

```
//fires first
$("#myform").submit(function(){
  if (some validation) {
    alert("You need to make the form valid");
    return false;
  }
});
//fires second
$("#myform").submit(function(){
  //ajax stuff
  return false;
});
```

p.s. I have to this as the ajax stuff is in a plugin that is not changeable. I cannot avoid two event handlers

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have a look at [`event.stopImmediatePropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopImmediatePropagation/):

> Keeps the rest of the handlers from being executed and prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree.

```
$("#myform").submit(function(event){
  if (some validation) {
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    alert("You need to make the form valid");
    return false;
  }
});
```

You might also want to use [`event.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/).

**Update:** Just to clarify: You can rely on the order the event handlers are called. From jQuery's [`bind`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) method:

> When an event reaches an element, all handlers bound to that event type for the element are fired. **If there are multiple handlers registered, they will always execute in the order in which they were bound.** After all handlers have executed, the event continues along the normal event propagation path.

The order might not be defined in W3C's original definition but it works with jQuery. Otherwise, the above named function would be unnecessary anyway ;)

Comment: how do you ascertain that this event handler will be called first?

Comment: @Here Be Wolves: Event handlers will be called in the order they are attached to the element.

Comment: IMO, depending upon the *order* of event handlers is a *very* bad idea.

Comment: its is well defined, but little known. Developers are prone to ignore the order of the code if they think it doesn't matter.

Comment: Note that the order the event handlers are run is undefined in DOM2 and is specified in DOM3 working draft and WHATWG specs. The order jQuery runs events listened by `jQuery.on(...)` is always well defined. However, there's no standard way to signal anything back to first handler in case second wants to cancel the form submission. In practice, you can set e.g. `form.my_allow_submit = false` and instead of running the full code in `submit` handler, do `setTimeout(..., 0)` to allow all the other submit handlers to run before running the code via timeout after browser event loop runs after events

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64857928/334451

Answer (score 2):

In short, no. If you have two event handlers, then you have two event handlers. That said however, there are ways around it.

First, remember that javascript execution is single-threaded. If you define a global variable, say `var haveCalledSubmit=0;`, then you can use that to synch your handlers. For example, if you start each handler function with this:

```
if(haveCalledSubmit == 1)return haveCalledSubmit = 0;
else haveCalledSubmit = 1;
```

Then only one of the two handlers will be called. You can easily modify it to match some condition, or to deal with more than two functions.

An alternative is to look into event propagation models. [This page](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html) will give you all the information you need, although Felix has already mentioned an ajax command that may do what you want.