# FormData doesn't include value of buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, form-data

Consider the following snippet:

```js
$('#myBtn').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    var formElement = $(this).closest('form')[0];
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("POST", "https://posttestserver.com/post.php");
    request.send(new FormData(formElement));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="POST" action="https://posttestserver.com/post.php">
  <input type="text" name="wtf" />
  <button type="submit" name="lol" value="cats" id="myBtn">
    Huh
  </button>
</form>
```

*(Have your developer tools open and watch for HTTP requests.)*

When you click on the button, any text you entered into the textbox is included in the POST request. However, the `lol=cats` pair from the button itself is not.

How can I make [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects) include the data given by buttons?

Comment: Button is not input type , so it can not pass value to POST request

Comment: Are you testing in Firefox? Check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38277900/formdata-object-does-not-add-submit-type-inputs-from-form-while-on-firefox

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: Chrome but same in FF

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: Accepted answer there seems to accurately describe and explain what's happening here

Comment: In that case it's possible other browsers have updated to follow the standard. To be honest I've always found support for sending the submit button value in the request a little flaky. I'd add it to the request manually, if possible.

Comment: I did close it as a dupe, but realised it may be no longer be a Firefox specific issue, so reopened :)

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: Barmar quoted the spec which explains this - think dupe is fine

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Because the call to `FormData`'s constructor doesn't know that it was triggered by a click on a submit button (let alone which submit button it was), and because you only want the *used* submit button's values included, the submit button isn't included in the posted data. You can use `FormData.append` to include desired pair.

```js
$('#myBtn').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var formElement = $(this).closest('form')[0];
    var formData = new FormData(formElement);
    formData.append("lol","cats");
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("POST", "https://posttestserver.com/post.php");
    request.send(formData);
});
```

```html
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <form method="POST" action="https://posttestserver.com/post.php">
      <input type="text" name="wtf" />
      <button type="submit" id="myBtn">
        Huh
      </button>
    </form>
```

Comment: Oh yeah, because the `FormData` constructor doesn't know which button I pressed :D

Comment: The hidden input will need dynamically populating with the right value depending on what button I clicked, but I suppose that's a different task now.

Comment: Actually in my case it's the best way as the click handler is really an `ajaxSubmitForm` function generic across all forms in my application, but for this example yes :)

Answer (score 8):

As you have already stated, FormData cannot know the button’s name. But when you catch a form submission, you can get the name through the [`submitter` property on the event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubmitEvent/submitter):

```js
const form = document.querySelector("form")

form.addEventListener("submit", ev => {
    ev.preventDefault()

    const data = {}

    for (const field of new FormData(form)) {
        data[field[0]] = field[1]
    }

    // NB: we are setting "none" as a fallback in case the form
    // has been submitted without clicking a button, e.g. by 
    // hitting enter in an input field.

    data.action = ev.submitter ? ev.submitter.name : "none"

    // … and so on
})
```

Comment: Note that as of April 2021, `submitter` is NOT supported by Safari (desktop or mobile), making this a poor option if you need to support all major browsers.

Comment: Thanks for this information, I didn’t know that. Do you have a suggestion what we could use instead?

Comment: I do not. I've been fighting trying to find a solution for an issue I'm having, and also thought this was a great solution until I tested in Safari :(

Comment: A patch has landed according to https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=229660 but not in safari yet.

Comment: Safari 15.4 will have full support, according to [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubmitEvent/submitter), but still, according to [can_i_use](https://caniuse.com/?search=submitter) only 74% full support globally.

Answer (score 4):

If I do `new FormData(event.target)` in Safari I get the buttons data. In Chrome I do not. In Safari `event.submitter` is always `none`, but in Chrome it works. So it seems like if I just do:

```js
let data = new FormData(event.target);
if (event.submitter) {
    data.append(event.submitter.name, event.submitter.value)
}
```

then I get the desired behavior in both Safari and Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

The spec was updated to support [passing a `submitter` to `FormData`](https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#interface-formdata), and the feature [is available](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData#browser_compatibility) in the latest version of major browsers ([Chrome](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1410542), [Firefox](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1812696), [Safari](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=251220)). For browsers that don't support it, you can use the [formdata-submitter-polyfill](https://www.npmjs.com/package/formdata-submitter-polyfill) package. This way you can reliably create `FormData` objects that match equivalent native form submissions (i.e. including the submit button's entry(s), if appropriate).

The basic usage in a submit handler would then look something like this:

```js
myform.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const formData = new FormData(e.target, e.submitter);
  // do something with formData...
});
```

Depending on which browser versions you're targeting, you might want to use the [event-submitter-polyfill](https://www.npmjs.com/package/event-submitter-polyfill) package as well, which ensures the `submitter` property is set on `SubmitEvent`.

Answer (score -1):

All you have to do is to add an input type hidden element. You will see to key value lol:cats to be attached in payload.

```js
$('#myBtn').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    var formElement = $(this).closest('form')[0];
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("POST", "https://posttestserver.com/post.php");
    request.send(new FormData(formElement));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="POST" action="https://posttestserver.com/post.php">
  <input type="text" name="wtf" />
  <input type="hidden" name="lol" value="cats" />
  <button type="submit" id="myBtn">
    Huh
  </button>
</form>
```