# Why doesn't data from my form buttons make it to my PHP server?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I'm sending form data to a server using ajax, I receive all data server side in the $_POST array except data from the submit buttons.

HTML

```
<form id="mainForm" action="#" class="form-inline" enctype="multipart/form- 
data">
...
    <div id="success"></div>
    <button type="submit" id="makegocard" name="makegocard" value="clicked" 
    form="mainForm" class="btn btn-primary">Make My WebGoCard</button>

    <div id="preview"></div>
    <button type="submit" id="previewgocard" name="previewgocard" 
    form="mainForm" class="btn btn-primary">Preview My WebGoCard</button>
</form>
```

javascript JQuery AJAX:

```
$("#mainForm input,#mainForm textarea,#mainForm 
 button").jqBootstrapValidation({
    //preventSubmit: true,
    submitError: function($form, event, errors) {},
    submitSuccess: function($form, event) {
        //$("#btnSubmit").attr("disabled", true);
        event.preventDefault();

        var mainFormData = new FormData(event.target);

        $.ajax({
            url: "./addUserToDB.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: mainFormData,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function(pResp) {
                $("#btnSubmit").attr("disabled", false);
                $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-success'>");
                $('#success > .alert-success').html("<button type='button' 
                class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria- 
                hidden='true'>&times;").append("</button>");
                $('#success > .alert-success').append(pResp);
                $('#success > .alert-success').append('</div>');
                //$('#mainForm').trigger("reset");
            },
            error: function(pError) {
                $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-danger'>");
                $('#success > .alert-danger').html("<button type='button' 
                class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria- 
                hidden='true'>&times;").append("</button>");
                $('#success > .alert-danger').append(pError);
                $('#success > .alert-danger').append('</div>');
                //$('#mainForm').trigger("reset");
            },
        })
    },
    filter: function() {
        return $(this).is(":visible");
    },
});
```

PHP:

```
echo print_r($_POST);
if(isset($_POST['makegocard'])){
...
}
```

The echo shows everything except the button data and the if statment alwasy returns false?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What version of jQuery?

Comment: Also the event.target is it not a button? Perhaps try  
`var mainFormData = new FormData(document.getElementById("mainForm"));`

Comment: Thanks for the help, it's jQuery v3.3.1, I got the same results after making that change, unfortunately.

Comment: You have to add the button that was clicked to the formdata because of the   event.preventDefault();

Comment: Can you give me a code example?

Comment: It looks like it passes the submit event.

Comment: `var whichBut = {};
$("button[form=mainForm]").on("click",function() { whichBut.name=this.name; whichBut.value=this.value });` and then `var mainFormData = new FormData(event.target); mainFormData.set(whichBut.name,whichBut.value); `

Comment: Thanks! That worked :)

Comment: I posted  as an answer because your validation made it more complex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In principle a duplicate of [FormData doesn't include value of buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48322876/formdata-doesnt-include-value-of-buttons)

But since you have a validation you need to do

```
var whichBut = {}; 
$("button[form=mainForm]").on("click",function() { 
  whichBut.name=this.name; 
  whichBut.value=this.value; 
});
```

and then later

```
var mainFormData = new FormData(event.target); 
mainFormData.set(whichBut.name,whichBut.value);
```