# How to access name and value pair of <button type="submit"> with php using Fetch API?

Tags: php, button, fetch, http-post, submit

I need the name and value of a button (Not an input type = submit) when a form is submitted with the button of type submit.

I know everyone always asks why, even though the "why" is not a part of the answer to the question so I will answer the why to save time. I want a form to direct a person to choose to login, register or submit email verification. So having buttons that I can set the label for, with each have a unique value for a given name would solve this need but the name and values are not included in the POST with the rest of the input data when BUTTON type = submit is used.

Given the information in HTML5 Spec as shown on this site https://www.htmlquick.com/reference/tags/button-submit.html it seems like it's supposed to work. But short of adding javascript to manually add the key value pair to the post on click it doesn't seem to work.

Now, I want to ask why? If only inputs can be added to the data list then why isn't there an option to change the label of the submit inputs?

*EDIT
So far everyone agrees that what I've done should work, so lets get to the specific case and see if we can find where the problem is then.

Using this form:

```
<form data-targetblock="accountBlock" class="fetchForm" action="<?=ADDRESS ?>/MAINhubs/accountBlockHub.php" method="post">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Member Login</legend>
    <input type="hidden" name="formTarget1" value="test">
    <button type="submit" name="formTarget" value="login">Log In</button>
    <button type="submit" name="formTarget" value="register">Register</button>
    <button type="submit" name="formTarget" value="verify">Verify Your Email</button>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Sent with this:

```
function addFetch(event, targetBlock, domain)
{
  event.preventDefault();
  const form = new FormData(event.target);
  const request = new Request(event.target.action,
  {
    method: event.target.method,
    body: form,
    mode: 'same-origin',
    credentials: 'same-origin'
  });

  fetch(request)
  .then(response => {
    if(response.ok)
    {
      return response.text();
    }
    else
    {
      document.getElementById(targetBlock).innerHTML = 'ERROR! ERROR! There has been an ERROR!'
    }
  })
  .then(function(text){document.getElementById(targetBlock).innerHTML = text;})
  .catch(error => console.log('There was an error:', error))
}
```

Going to this:

```
<?php
session_start();

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === "POST")
{
    var_dump($_POST);
}
?>
```

Gets me this when I click Log In:

> formTarget1 = test

I'm gonna guess it has to do with this line in the Fetch:

```
const form = new FormData(event.target);
```

To answer the question of how the function is called, this JS is run to add the function to all applicable forms:

```
function fetchFormCallback(mutations)
{
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation)
  {
    for (const thisForm of Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('fetchForm')))
    {
      addFormListener(thisForm, thisForm.dataset.targetblock)
    }
  });
}

function generalCallback(mutations)
{
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation)
  {
    // Take alertBlocks and move them to bottom of ID outerFrame because of IOS bug
    if (newAlertBlock = document.getElementById('alertMessageBlock'))
    {
      if (newAlertBlock.dataset.relocated !== 'true')
      {
        var destinationBlock = document.getElementById('outerFrame');
        destinationBlock.appendChild(newAlertBlock);
        newAlertBlock.dataset.relocated = 'true';
      }
    }
    // Get getElementsByClassName closeButton
    for (var closeButton of Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('closeButton')))
    {
      if (closeButton.dataset.closeButton !== 'true')
      {
        closeButton.dataset.closeButton = 'true';
        closeButton.addEventListener('click', function(){this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode);});
      }
    }
    // Potentially auto close based on a closeButton class of AUTO
  });
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function()
{
  var config = {childList: true};
  for (const thisForm of Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('fetchForm')))
  { // setup all fetchforms
    addFormListener(thisForm, thisForm.dataset.targetblock);
    var thisTargetBlock = document.getElementById(thisForm.dataset.targetblock);
    // if notset dataset.mutationobserver OR
    if (thisTargetBlock.dataset.mutationobserver !== 'true')
    {
      thisTargetBlock.dataset.mutationobserver = 'true';
      var observer = new MutationObserver(fetchFormCallback);
      observer.observe(thisTargetBlock, config);
    }
  }
  config = {childList: true, subtree: true};
  var generalObserver = new MutationObserver(generalCallback);
  generalObserver.observe(document, config);
});

function addFormListener(form, targetBlock)
{ // first check if element has attribute set for eventListeners
  if (form.dataset.submitlistener !== 'true')
  {
    form.dataset.submitlistener = 'true';
    form.addEventListener('submit', function()
    {
      addFetch(event, targetBlock);
    });
  }
}
```

EDIT:

We've confirmed that the issue here is that FormData is for some reason not supposed to include the submit value. Why a value should be excluded just because it may not be present/needed in the use case is beyond me. I do have a reason why it should be included and have documented it above. I developed this structure to be as universally applicable as possible without the addition of code for special case uses.

So now my evolving question has become this:

How; using the above functions, can I get the value of the clicked submit button, and include that name value pair in the FormData without changing the fundamental structure of these functions that otherwise do exactly what I want them to do in every other case.

This discussion illustrates that it's possible but has been reworked based on the spec to no longer do exactly what I'm trying to do:
[FormData() object does not add submit-type inputs from form, while on Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38277900/formdata-object-does-not-add-submit-type-inputs-from-form-while-on-firefox)

If I can't access the name and value of the button at the point of submition, then I might as well make another eventlistener to all BUTTON elements in forms that adds a hidden input with it's values on click...  Before I go and do that, I can already see hurdles like the event.preventDefault(); line in the addFetch function might prevent the on click from happening? I guess it's back to trial and error unless someone has a better thought.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your issue? Have you tried `$_POST['formTarget']`? Can you please show us the related PHP code as well?

Comment: Maybe we should be asking about your environment then. If the name and value **of the button you press** does not appear in $_POST there are other issues

Comment: Yes, that's what I suspect but can't for the life of me figure out what could be wrong. I've come to this method due to other factors which may be relevant, this form is being submitted as you might suspect using the fetch api to insert the returned page into a specific part of the open page.

Comment: Updated the question with specifics that may be causing the problem.

Comment: Can you provide how you are calling this function? Also FormData does not include a submit button value.

Comment: Added the "How" for calling this function. But it looks like you already know FormData is the problem. How would I go about adding the submit button values to the FormData given the shown code? I'm gonna guess there's something I can do to add the clicked button name and value to the FormData at the point of that line?

Comment: I've updated my answer to give you an alternative. Just quick and dirty didn't want to try to rewrite everything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your PHP:

```php
$_POST['formTarget'];
```

Will have the value of the submit button. Either login, register, etc.

However I would not use a form for this, there is no need. I would just simply use links and style them as buttons if you wanted them to look like a button.

Edit: Based on your additions to the post. I offer an alternative way to accomplish this using [data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes).

HTML:

```html
<fieldset>
    <legend>Member Login</legend>
    <button id="loginButton" data-url="getForm.php" data-target-block="#showForm" data-form-type="login">Log In</button>
    <button id="registerButton" data-url="getForm.php" data-target-block="#showForm" data-form-type="register">Register</button>
    <button id="verifyButton" data-url="getForm.php" data-target-block="#showForm" data-form-type="verify">Verify Your Email</button>
</fieldset>
<div id="showForm"></div>
<script>
    document.querySelector("#loginButton").addEventListener("click", addFetch);
    document.querySelector("#registerButton").addEventListener("click", addFetch);
    document.querySelector("#verifyButton").addEventListener("click", addFetch);
    function addFetch() {
        const data = new FormData;
        const targetBlock = this.dataset.targetBlock;
        for(element in this.dataset) {
            data.append(element, this.dataset[element]);
        }        
        const request = new Request(this.dataset.url,
        {
            method: "POST",
            body: data,
            mode: 'same-origin',
            credentials: 'same-origin',
        });
        fetch(request).then(response => {
            if(response.ok) {
            return response.text();
            } else {
            document.querySelector(targetBlock).innerHTML = 'ERROR! ERROR! There has been an ERROR!'
            }
        }).then(function(text){document.querySelector(targetBlock).innerHTML = text;})
        .catch(error => console.log('There was an error:', error))
    }
</script>
```

PHP:

```php
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === "POST") {
    switch($_POST['formType']) {
        case 'verify':
            echo "verify Form";
        break; 
        case 'register':
            echo "Register Form";
        break; 
        case 'login':
            echo "Login Form";
        break; 
        default:
            echo "Not valid";
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, this is exactly what I would say to this question and yet $_POST['formTarget'] doesn't exist when I submit this form. i tested by adding a hidden input with a name value and did a foreach loop to echo everything in $_POST and only the hidden input would show up. I appreciate the recommendation but I've come to this method due to other factors which may be relevant, this form is being submitted as you might suspect using the fetch api to insert the returned page into a specific part of the open page.

Comment: Here is my [test with your code](https://gist.github.com/pwncraft/df615c8d8fb500371da0c023165f8cb8). When you click on any of the buttons you get the formTarget value in $_POST.

Comment: I see many good reasons for the suggestion but I am trying to keep these functions as universal as possible, is there no way to take the full array of data sent in the $_POST and substitute it into this line instead of the FormData? `const form = new FormData(event.target)` I understand the spec says FormData is not to be aware of submit values but I'm left disagreeing with the spec and a workaround that defeats the purpose of the entire set of universal functions. Don't get me wrong, your help has been great in diagnosing the actual problem and now I'd just like to simplify the solution.

Comment: To me that is just not the proper use of a form. I've modified the JS in my answer to be more "universal". It will pass any data-* attribute as POST data to whatever URL is defined in data-url. If you want to use form for this either you will have to use a separate form for each button with a hidden input for your type. Or, manually add the type to your FormData by reading the value of the button. I really suggest not using a form for this.

Comment: The separate form for each button suggestion was what I was using before. As I'm going through my project I decided to have another look before finalizing it and refused to accept that this was the best solution. As you might guess, every choice made in this form leads to another form or choice and keeping everything hooked  up with the same JS allows complex admin menus without page after page of navigation confusion for the user. It could have been a checkbox and submit or radio and submit but I wanted a button for it's simplicity. It's my mess and you've helped me make it work. Thanks!

Comment: For the record, your point about the use of the button vs a link styled like a button is taken and accepted. The example I posted with this question is a case where the buttons do not at all have anything to do with form fields, but the purpose of this whole thing goes forward into deeper application where a search can lead to several displayed results and several form submit uses like: Open details of selected item or Delete selected items.