# React Semantic UI Form - Two submit buttons

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, semantic-ui

I'm pretty new at ReactJs, I'm trying to submit a form, but one of the form values must depend on which submit button triggers the submit

I've coded something like this

```
<Form onSubmit={(e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const {target} = e;
        console.log('FormData', Object.fromEntries(new FormData(target)));
      }}>
... form fields ...
<Button icon="thumbs up" type="submit" content="Authorize" name="status" value="A" positive />
<Button icon="thumbs down" type="submit" content="Reject" name="status" value="R" negative />
</Form>
```

The log shows all form values correctly but the "status" field.
Is there any way to achieve the expected behaviour? Any alternative is very welcome

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the status value from the submit button on the event.submitter property and append this to the FormData.

See this answer for more info:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/64857928/681058